# Is it right method to remove instances that are hard to predict before train test split?

Tags: machine-learning, python, training, class-imbalance, sampling

In a binary classification problem,

I have a slightly unbalanced medical dataset with class distribution:
0:5600, 1:1500
0 without a problem and 1 with a problem.

I tried many pipelines, automls, and threshold tuning etc and I am not getting "good" recall and precision at the same time. (I would like to get at least .75 recall and precision at the same time if possible.)

I assume class overlapping is there (no checking done yet) and I applied instance hardness threshold for removing hard to predict instances from class 0 (majority class) as undersampling.
Now my class distribution is like this:
0:1530, 1:1500

Then I split the undersampled data into train and test.
I know it is a bad idea to undersample data before train test split, since the test set will not be the true representation of real-world problem as stated in this stackexchange [question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/89132/undersampling-for-credit-card-fraud-detection-before-or-after-train-test-split).

But I wonder, is it right to do something like instance hardness threshold undersampling before training?
After doing so, I am getting all scores above 95%. But it is too optimistic!!
Kindly help me to clarify the doubt regarding this!

Comment: if you dont care about the hard instances, then all is fine. Else you should try to include them in test set

Comment: But if I include it in test set, since such kind of instances not seen while training, I am not getting good performance.

Comment: it is all about whether you care about the hard instances. If you dont care so much, then leave them out. Else include them both in train and test (at least a portion of them)

Comment: Thank you very much!